Hamming Code $H_3$ : Generator Matrix & Polynomial\ldots doesn't generate the same code. Why?
The generator matrix of the $H_3$ Hamming code is given by
$$
\mathcal{G} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and according to several course books, it is also generated by the generator polynomial
$$
g(x) = 1 + x + x^3.
$$
However, when I encode a message $m$ by calculating (1) $m\cdot\mathcal{G}$ and (2) $m(x) \cdot g(x)$, I don't get the same result! Morevoer, the whole linear/cylic code generated by $\mathcal{G}$ and $g(x)$ seems to be different!
Is there anyone that can clarify that?

Your generator polynomial is wrong (as there is no codeword (1101000) corresponding to it).
You can also verify that it is not the generator polynomial by constructing a generator matrix $G$ in the standard way from it, and checking that $GH^T \neq 0$ (where $H$ is the parity-check matrix of the code).
Also, in general, though the generator polynomial is unique, there may be several generator matrices for a given cyclic code, so encoding a message via the matrix and via the polynomial may not, in general, give you the same codeword. Though (of course) the total set of codewords would be the same.
Edit: @JordanPayette thank you for pointing out my mistake (which I have corrected above). Firstly, the $[7,4,3]$ Hamming code $H_3$ is not cyclic (the codeword (1110000) belongs to it, but it's cyclic shift (0111000) does not). So one cannot talk of the generator polynomial in this case. However, there exists a cyclic code with the same parameters $[7,4,3]$ for which the polynomial
$1+ x+x^3$ is a generator polynomial. As you have pointed out, this code is permutation equivalent to the Hamming code but not the same as it. In other words, one can permute the columns of the given generator matrix of $H_3$ to obtain the generator matrix of a cyclic code whose generator polynomial is $1+x+x^3$.

Thanks a lot for your clarification!

Could you please expand on your answer? As far as I understand the implicit conventions involved here, $x + x^2 + x^3$ should correspond to $g = (0111000)$, which does not satisfy $g H^T = 0$. I am under the impression that the polynomial $1 + x + x^3$ mentioned by @Number_Pi refers to another representation of the Hamming code. (Indeed, up to a switching of bits in the message and in the code, the code generated by $1 + x + x^3$ is equivalent to that generated by the matrix $G$ above.)

@JordanPayette thank you for your comment.  I have added an edit to my answer post.
